# uncaught error bootstrap requires jquery at bootstrap.min.js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting this error even when all the  jquery has been loaded before bootstrap and also have used the version 1.9.1

tried using jquery version 1.9.1 and it still dint solve

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


     <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/js/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/js/bootstrap-popover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cal/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cal/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cal/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.css">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this issue previously when I have referenced two different versions of jquery or Bootstrap, you have done both here. You have three versions of JQuery in this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You are also loading bootstrap and the bootstrap min js files which will interfere with each other.

Try simplifying your code and only use 1 version of each library/framework.

So one version of JQuery loaded before Bootstrap stuff. One version of bootstrap. So make sure you have your JQuery script src THEN your Bootstrap one.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to add more than one version of bootstrap this error comes. Order of bootstrap and jquery also matters. Try including this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try including this

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: no it did not work people are down voting this post i am really sad it is a genuine issue in browser

Comment: This will not work because you are loading the bootstrap JS before the Jquery, bootstrap requires JQ loaded prior. This also does not deal with the other libraries already loaded.